# Drop aggregate operation in domain layer

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Order aggregate has Status attribute. Which can take the values: pending, processing, cancelled, completed. But exist rule - only aggregate with status peinding may be removed. Where to place this rule in domain or application layer?

Cases

- domain, for example, describe as domain service, but this service look like usecase - find order, check status, drop order operations
- application, for example, describe as usecase, but something is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If it's a business rule, place it in your Domain. That's the whole point of DDD.